# Accessing values in a list

Tags: python, list

```
new_list = [1, "hello"]
is_str = (type(str) is True)
for element in new_list:
    if (element is is_str):
        element = element.upper()
```

I am trying to create a loop that runs through each element in a list, then returns the element in uppercase if a string is found. However, for some reason, my if statement does not seem to be working in my favour. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that `is_str` is `False`, and no element of `new_list` is identical to `False`.

Comment: `if isinstance(element, str):`.

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: But, if my loop is checking each element in the list, would it not eventually run through "hello" and pass it off as a str?

Comment: The output is the same as input, [1, "hello"]

Comment: `(type(str) is True)` resolves to `False` and therefore you will never enter the body of the `if` statement.

Comment: @user498021 Your code doesn't check for strings. It checks whether any element is identical to `False`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, why does my is_str evaluate to False?

Comment: @user498021 Because the type of `str` is not `True`. `True` isn't a type in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Try This ( Normal way ):

```
new_list = [1, "hello"]

for element in new_list:

    if isinstance(element, str):
        element = element.upper()
        print(element)
```

**Pythonic Way :**

```
new_list = [1, "hello", "ssss"]
your_data = [element.upper() for element in new_list if isinstance(element, str)]
print(your_data)
```

Another Way:

```
new_list = [1, "hello", None]

for element in new_list:

    if type(element) is str:
        element = element.upper()
        print(element)
```

About Your Comment :

```
new_list = [1, "hello", None, "hi", "book"]

for counter, element in enumerate(new_list):

    if isinstance(element, str):
        new_list[counter] = element.upper()

print(new_list)
```

Comment: How would I return the changed list as a list and not just the element?

Comment: So in this case, I want it to be [1, "HELLO"]

Comment: @user498021: Done! :) may you tick me plz.

Comment: Can you do this with the "Another way" method? I do not want to use enumerate and counter

Comment: @user498021: yes! if you do not have same values in your list.

Comment: How do you do it?

Comment: What do you mean with index?

Comment: @user498021: Why did you get your tick back?

Comment: @user498021: i can update my answer with index() function. do you like it?

Answer (score 0):

Single liner using `List Comprehension` :

```
>>> [x.upper() for x in l if isinstance(x, str)]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [1, 'adsa', 3, 'ASD']
OUT : ['ADSA', 'ASD']
```

---

The problem you are facing is due to your usage of `element` to `update the list`. Use the `index` instead for the updation.

```
for i, element in enumerate(new_list):
    if type(element)==str:
        new_list[i] = element.upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

The more [Pythonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) way to do this would be not checking if the element is a string at all:

```
for element in new_list:
    try:
        uppercase_element = element.upper()
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # Skip this element as it can't be uppercased
    else:
        print uppercase_element
```

One concrete reason this works better than checking if the element is a string is, in Python 2, Unicode objects are not strings but they can be uppercased (and probably should be in the example you provided).

Comment: Is printing in the `else` better than just doing it in the `try` (and not having an `else`)?

Comment: It's better to only do in the `try` block what will raise the error you're catching.  However, in this example, if you're desperate to save SLOC, you can get away with doing both.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I ever used `try`+`else`, and never considered this issue. But I see the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) also says *"The use of the else clause is better [...]"*. Now I'm wondering: If that second line could cause a different error, would you then have another `try` nested/indented inside that `else`? And a third would be further nested/indented?